# How to check previous row value with present row value in dataframe

Tags: r

How to check previous row value with present row value dynamically for all column of data frame by grouping specific ID.

my data frame:

```
ID  ITEM1     ITEM2    ITEM3           
  1    A         A        A     
  2    C         B        C       
  1    A         B        C
  1    B         A        C    
  2    NA        B        F      
  3    A         A        D     
  4    R         G        J 
  4    H         T        J
```

For Ex:

```
ID  ITEM1     ITEM2    ITEM3    ITEM1change  ITEM2change   ITEM3change                   
  1    A         A        A       0            0             0          
  1    A         B        C       0            1             1
  1    B         A        C       1            1             0 
  2    C         B        C       0            0             0
  2    NA        B        F       1            0             1
  3    A         A        D       0            0             0
  4    R         G        J       0            0             0
  4    H         T        J       1            1             0
```

My final output will be:

```
  Fiels         modifiedcout   unmodifiedcount Total      
  ITEM1change     3               5              8                
  ITEM2change     3               5              8    
  ITEM3change     2               6              8
```

my data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4), ITEM1 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "H", "R"
), class = "factor"), ITEM2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), 
    ITEM3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", 
    "C", "D", "F", "J"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Something like `c(0,as.integer(as.boolean(diff(as.numeric(as.factor(yourcol)))))` should work

Comment: Note that in your example you could simply count unique items

Comment: Should not  be there `as.logical()` instead of `as.boolean()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(item, value, -1) %>% 
  group_by(ID, item) %>% 
  mutate(change = lag(value, default = first(value)) != value,
         change = replace(change, is.na(change), TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  summarise(modified = sum(change, na.rm = TRUE),
            unmodified = sum(!change, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(total = modified + unmodified)
```

which gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
>    item modified unmodified total
>   <chr>    <int>      <int> <int>
> 1 ITEM1        3          5     8
> 2 ITEM2        3          5     8
> 3 ITEM3        2          6     8
> ```

Comment: Thanks for instance response ,At the same time i need to sum NA value as one count ,  ex:   ITEM1        3          5     8. please tell me how to do that..

Comment: ,At the same can you please help me how to  group_by multiple column.

Comment: @udya I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Could you explain in more detail what your problem is?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea using `rollapply` from `zoo`. By using `rollapply` with `width = 2`, we are testing if `x` is not equal with `x-1`. Wrapping it in `as.integer` gives 1s (`TRUE`) and 0s (`FALSE`). We then replace all `NA`s with 1 since you consider them as being modified, and use `colSums` to sum the modified/unmodified elements. The total is just the number of rows of the original data frame.

```
library(zoo)

m1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(i) 
                     sapply(i[-1], function(j) 
                     as.integer(c(FALSE, rollapply(j, 2, function(k) k[1] != k[2]))))))

m1 <- replace(m1, is.na(m1), 1)

#giving

#   ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3
#      0     0     0
#      0     1     1
#      1     1     0
#      0     0     0
#      1     0     1
#3     0     0     0
#      0     0     0
#      1     1     0
```

To get your expected data frame,

```
final_df <- data.frame(modified = colSums(m1 == 1), 
                       unmodified = colSums(m1 != 1), 
                       Total = nrow(df), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

which gives,

> ```
>        modified unmodified Total
> ITEM1        3          5     8
> ITEM2        3          5     8
> ITEM3        2          6     8
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The given data has many columns of the same type. This strongly suggests that the data better be stored in long format rather than in wide format.

[Jaap's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46068239/3817004) is reshaping the data using `tidyr` / `dplyr`.

However, I would like to suggest a `data.table`solution which does not reshape the data. In addition, it avoids to handle `NA` values separately.

```
library(data.table)
# coerce to data.table, loop over columns and determine changes to previous row by ID
tmp <- setDT(DF)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x == shift(x, fill = x[1])), by = ID]
tmp
```

> ```
>    ID ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3
> 1:  1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> 2:  1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> 3:  1 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> 4:  2  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> 5:  2    NA  TRUE FALSE
> 6:  3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> 7:  4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> 8:  4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> ```

Now, we can count the unchanged rows:

```
tmp[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = -"ID"]
```

> ```
>    ITEM1 ITEM2 ITEM3
> 1:     5     5     6
> ```

From here, OP's expected result can be achieved in two different ways

using `melt()`

```
melt(tmp[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = -"ID"]
     , measure.vars = patterns("^ITEM"), 
     variable.name = "item", 
     value.name = "unmodified")[
       , c("modified", "Total") := .(nrow(DF) - unmodified, nrow(DF))][]
```

or by transposing:

```
as.data.table(
  t(tmp[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = -"ID"])
  , keep.rownames = "item")[, setnames(.SD, "V1", "unmodified")][
    , c("modified", "Total") := .(nrow(DF) - unmodified, nrow(DF))][]
```

Both return the same result:

> ```
>     item unmodified modified Total
> 1: ITEM1          5        3     8
> 2: ITEM2          5        3     8
> 3: ITEM3          6        2     8
> ```

---

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` implementation of the reshape approach. As above, `NA` are handled by counting the unmodified rows first excluding any `NA`.

```
melt(setDT(DF), id.vars = "ID", variable.name = "item")[
  , value == shift(value, fill = value[1L]), by = .(ID, item)][
    , .(unmodified = sum(V1, na.rm = TRUE)), by = item][
      , c("modified", "Total") := .(nrow(DF) - unmodified, nrow(DF))][]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `dat` is your data, then try:

Create `ITEMCHANGE` variables

```
dat["ITEM1Change"] <- c(NA, head(dat["ITEM1"], dim(dat)[1] - 1)[[1]])
dat["ITEM2Change"] <- c(NA, head(dat["ITEM2"], dim(dat)[1] - 1)[[1]])
dat["ITEM3Change"] <- c(NA, head(dat["ITEM3"], dim(dat)[1] - 1)[[1]])
```

Then compare if there are changes

```
dat$ITEM1Change <- ifelse(dat$ITEM1Change == dat$ITEM1, 0, 1)
dat$ITEM2Change <- ifelse(dat$ITEM2Change == dat$ITEM2, 0, 1)
dat$ITEM3Change <- ifelse(dat$ITEM3Change == dat$ITEM2, 0, 1)
```

Then group and summarize

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by("ITEM1") %>%
  summarise_at(.funs = sum, .vars = "ITEM1Change") -> ITEM1Change

etc.
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: ,Thanks for response ,but my doubt is dynamically add column,For example if have 50 to 100 item of column means how can i add manually, Thats why i need dynamically create and sum modified count and unmodified count.